# Should the common usage "Webmasters" be gender neutered into a separate webmistresses to describe female web site admin professionals?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-gender

Should the common usage "Webmasters" be gender neutered into a separate webmistresses to describe female web site admin professionals?

Specifically why do we really need a term like web mistresses? Is it due to PC standards that say you shouldn't refer to a woman by a inherently male term?

I like to think that common usage comes from the way people prefer to use English. So if they stick to the term Webmaster, they are not necessarily doing so due to an inherent byass towards a male term.

Comment: I have fixed a few typos, but I absolutely *had* to leave "inherent byass", it's too cool a word. (^_^)

Comment: Using *webmistress* in addition to *webmaster* is the opposite of becoming gender neutral.

Comment: @RegDwight, why thankyou. @Kosmonaut why do you say that, I would actually argue the opposite where a second word is introduced soley to counter the gender byass of the first word.

Comment: I would have thought of the term "master" being more racist than sexist.

Comment: @user744, why would you say that? Master is no more inherently racist than describing the colour of someones skin is racist.

Comment: Webmaster is currently gender neutral, so it doesn't need neutering. I think you mean does it need gender specifying, or possibly gender disambiguating or maybe even just gendering. The answer is probably no; that's no longer the way of these things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a strong tendency in recent English to eliminate gender-specific words. For example, most female actors do not want to be called 'actresses' (though there are a few that do want to).

For this reason, and because of Claudiu's point as well, I would suggest not coining any new words in "-mistress".

Comment: Agreed.  I think it would be best if we stop making gender-specific names.  Where they are currently specific, keep them, but stop assuming anything about gender.  Like, a man who calls himself a ___master would no longer be implicitly saying he is male, just that he is the one controlling ___.  If we stop saying that the -er suffix is an indicator of gender, I think a lot of problems will just go away.  Consider "controller", "officer", "lawyer", etc.  No one assumes any of those is male.  So we don't need "controlless", "officess", or "lawyess".

Comment: Actually, those would historically have been "controlleress", "officeress" and "lawyeress", @AikenDrum. The last two of these are actually in the OED. As it happens, "controlleress" isn't, and "controlless" is - but in the meaning "uncontrolled"! But I am not disagreeing with your point.

Comment: Fair enough.  :)  I'd say the fact that I'm not even aware of the gendered terms is a good sign that they've fallen into disuse, at least.  As an aside, what a horrible construct "officeress" would have been to use and say.  No wonder they died out.

Comment: It qualifies "officeress" as "rare", but it has a citation as recently as 1979, from Norman Mailer, no less. And the NOW corpus contains a single instance, from 2012.

Answer (score 9):

Webmaster, to me, can mean a person of any sex. Additionally, 'mistress' has the connotation to me of an S&M mistress, or a concubine, etc., not of a female master, so saying Webmistress sounds pretty strange to me.

Comment: The British organisation that used to be called the National Union of Schoolmasters and Mistresses has changed its name to the National Union of Schoolmasters / Association of Women Teachers, presumably for this reason.

Comment: @Brian how interesting.

Comment: @Brian: You may be confusing the [NASUWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Association_of_Schoolmasters_Union_of_Women_Teachers) with the [ATL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_of_Teachers_and_Lecturers), formerly called the *Assistant Masters and Mistresses Association* after the merger of the *Association of Assistant Mistresses* and the *Association of Assistant Masters in Secondary Schools*

Answer (score 7):

In my personal experience working at various web companies, both males and females were referred to as webmasters. Regardless of whether 'webmaster' has gender connotations, the term is becoming obsolete, so this will probably end up a moot point over time.

Comment: "the term is becoming obsolete": could you provide some evidence of this?

Answer (score 6):

As Kosmonaut said, "webmistress" is the complete opposite of gender neutral.

There *is* an actual trend toward gender neutrality in occupational terms: *flight attendant* instead of *stewardess*, *mail carrier* instead of *postman*, that sort of thing. There is also some tendency toward avoiding the -ress form of some occupations; *actor* for both genders instead of *actor/actress* is the most prominent example, but people do still use *actress*.

Comment: "As the actress said to the bishop" wouldn't work so well otherwise.

Comment: no I disagree regarding your point of gender neutrality. Sure your examples are all correct, however those examples are for nouns that are already gender neutral, Webmaster is not. The usage of webmistress counterbalances, and would make it neutral, however I think your partially correct in alluding to the need for a new term that gets rid of the "master", and is therefore more inclusive.

Comment: @Anonymous Type: creating a new gender-specific term makes the language *less* gender-neutral, not more. Right now, "webmaster" can be used to refer to either a male or a female. If you decide that a "master" can't be female (whyever not?), and thus invent a need for the term "webmistress", then you've created a gender polarity where there didn't used to be one.

Comment: true interesting point. thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [International Webmasters Association website](http://iwanet.org/about/mission-statement/) I think you'll find they're not an exclusive group.

[The dictionary defines master as](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/master) :

> a person with the ability or power to use, control, or dispose of
> something:
>
> a person eminently skilled in something, as an occupation
> art, or science:

I think it's fairly clear that a webmaster is not a gendered term.